# ()[]+! in javascript

Tags: javascript

How is it possible to only use ()[]+! to make javascript code?

Ex:
http://discogscounter.getfreehosting.co.uk/js-noalnum.php

Comment: What on earth is that page converting to? If you click convert on the example JS you get 6092 characters of this: ([][(![]+[])[!+[]+!+...

Comment: What the hell?  Surely there has to be better obfuscation methods out there...

Comment: Holy hell.  I literally laughed when i clicked "convert" xD

Comment: This is a pretty legit question.  John Resig commented on it recently in his recent Tweet: http://twitter.com/jeresig/statuses/9701921677 - "Wrote a reply on Hacker News explaining why ++[[]][+[]] == 1 in JavaScript: http://j.mp/cmXC4C"

Comment: That is why I had to ask. I was baffled when I saw his tweet!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [Java/script: no alnum cheat sheets](http://sla.ckers.org/forum/read.php?24,33349,33405).

In short, various constructs yield NaN/undefined/window/etc.  Stringify and index them to yield any string.  Extract a property and call it to execute code.

Comment: It doesn't, it yields 0 (in 3 characters).  To get 3, use `3=true+true+true=!0+!0+!0=!+[]+!+[]+!+[]`.